# Quiero centrar los input de name, email y age con el form, pero salen desplazados a la derecha

Tags: html, css

Comparto los archivos para que me puedan ayudar.

Como verán, los recuadros de los input sobresalen del lado derecho del recuadro del formulario, no se si es realmente un error de código (que debe ser lo mas probable) o no se puede porque los elementos ocupan un espacio mínimo y no puedo mantener el `width` al `100%`.
La solución fue extraer el `input` del `label` y aplicando los códigos que sugirió @René.

```css
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh ;
    background-color: rgb(206, 206, 211);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-family: Tahoma;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-image: url(https://www.parati.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/feng-shui.deco_-564x561.jpeg.webp);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    margin: 0 0;
}
fieldset {
    margin: 0 0;
    padding: 2rem 0;
}
form {
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 300px;
    background-color: rgba(209, 222, 224, 0.589);
    margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
    margin: 0.5rem 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    display: block;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 1em 0 0 0;
    padding: 0 0;
    min-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
        <fieldset>
            <label id="name-label">NAME<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></label>
            <label id="email-label">EMAIL<input id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your Email"></label>
            <label id="age-label">AGE<input min="13" max="110" id="number" type="number" required placeholder="Age"></label>
        </fieldset>
```

Comment: Ya intentaste con `align-items: center; display: flex; justify-content: center;` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los inputs se sobresalen de su elemento padre (el `fieldset`) porque le estás quitando el margen (en los 4 lados) y espaciado (izquierdo y derecho) a `fieldset`:

```
fieldset {
  margin: 0 0;
  padding: 2rem 0;
}
```

Bastaría con darle un `padding` a los 4 lados, así los inputs respetan el margen de su contenedor padre, teniendo un espaciado y un mejor aspecto:

```
fieldset {
  padding: 2rem;
}
```

**Ejemplo:**

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh ;
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 211);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-image: url(https://www.parati.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/feng-shui.deco_-564x561.jpeg.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 0;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 2rem;
}
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(209, 222, 224, 0.589);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  display: block;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  min-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label id="name-label">NAME<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></label>
  <label id="email-label">EMAIL<input id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your Email"></label>
  <label id="age-label">AGE<input min="13" max="110" id="number" type="number" required placeholder="Age"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Si quieres centrarlo completamente, solo agregamos estas propiedades a `fieldset`:

```
fieldset {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Donde indico que su posición es absoluta, tendrá un ancho del `80%` en toda la pantalla, tendrá un espacio por encima y por la izquierda un `50%` y lo trasladamos al centro (eje `x`: `-50%` y eje `y`: `-50%`) para que quede perfectamente centrado.

**Ejemplo:**

```css
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh ;
  background-color: rgb(206, 206, 211);
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-family: Tahoma;
  font-size: 16px;
  background-image: url(https://www.parati.com.ar/wp-content/uploads/2022/01/feng-shui.deco_-564x561.jpeg.webp);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0 0;
}
fieldset {
  padding: 2rem;
  position: absolute;
  width: 80%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
form {
  max-width: 500px;
  min-width: 300px;
  background-color: rgba(209, 222, 224, 0.589);
  margin: 0 auto;
}
label {
  margin: 0.5rem 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  display: block;
}
input {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1em 0 0 0;
  padding: 0 0;
  min-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <label id="name-label">NAME<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter your name" required></label>
  <label id="email-label">EMAIL<input id="email" type="email" required placeholder="Enter your Email"></label>
  <label id="age-label">AGE<input min="13" max="110" id="number" type="number" required placeholder="Age"></label>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: te agradezco mucho por tu tiempo y correcciones, pero sigo notando una diferencia, de ´padding´ o desplazamiento del elemento, no se encuentra centrado por completo en el ejemplo que compartiste, si pudieras corregirlo u orientarme aun más te lo agradecería

Comment: No hay de que, ¿lo visualizaste en pantalla completa?, ¿o cuál es el inconveniente que estás teniendo?.

Comment: Soy muy nuevo en este asunto y es muy probable que este cometiendo algún error, pero cuando yo lo visualizo en pantalla completa hay una diferencia de 1mm aprox. de espesor de un lado en comparación al otro (es muy minucioso).

Comment: Bueno... no es un gran problema tampoco... me imagino que será un detalle tan minucioso que no creo que sea tan notorio... aunque los márgenes están en la unidad de medida `rem` **por igual** en los 4 lados, así que no creo que haya problemas...

Comment: No, no es un problema como tal, estoy aprendiendo, centrar considero que es algo dentro de lo mas básico y me frustro al no poder lograrlo. Nuevamente gracias por tu tiempo.

Comment: Esta bien estimado, recuerda verificar la respuesta marcándole al ✔️ (que se encuentra al lado izquierdo de mi respuesta) si te sirvió para que tu pregunta esté como respondida, saludos.